# href to controller action in dynamically made html in javascript

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am having a problem in specifying the `controller` and `action method` in javascript. For the other redirection i am using

`$this->Html->link('Path', array("controller" => "users", "action" => "get", '85'), ["target" => "_blank"])`

but now i am making the html in `javascript` in the response. so i cannot specify the `php` functions. Moreover i cannot specify the baseurl in `app.php` because i have to run it on multiple domains. So is there any method which redirect me to the controller and method like the `cakephp`  `helper` function doing?

Comment: Use javascript `window.location = 'http://....';`

Comment: @shahonseven yeah it worked in this way.